# Route [compose-update] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\test\news\resources\views\admin\compose\edit.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-5.8

**I just want to edit my compose fields all fields in the table come to me and update it but when I am trying to edit this error will occur and I have checked my code for a long time but unfortunately I could not find the error to solve please help as soon as possible  ...**

**my web.php**

```
Route::get('/compose/edit/{id}', ['uses'=>'Admin\ComposeController@edit','as'=>'compose-edit', 'middleware'=> 'permission:All'] );

Route::put('/compose/update/{id}', ['uses'=>'Admin\ComposeController@update','as'=>'update-compose', 'middleware'=> 'permission:All'] );
```

**mycontroller**

```
public function edit($id)
    {
         $page_name = 'Edit Compose';
        $compose = Cpost::find($id);
        return view('admin.compose.edit',compact('page_name','compose'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
          'sms_title'=>'required', 
          'offer_name'=>'required',
          'sms_content'=>'required',
 
      ],[

        'sms_title.required' => "The SMS Title Field is Required",
        'offer_name.required' => "The Offer Name Field is Required",
        'sms_content.required' => "The SMS Content Field is Required",

        ]);


         $compose = Cpost::find($id);
         $compose->sms_title = $request->sms_title;
         $compose->offer_name = $request->offer_name;
         $compose->sms_content = $request->sms_content;
         $compose->languages = $request->languages;
         
         $compose->save();
        return redirect()->action('Admin\ComposeController@index')->with('success','Compose Updated Successfully');
    }
```

**my blade.php**

```
{{ Form::model($compose,['route' => ['update-compose',$compose->id],'method'=>'put']) }} 
                                 
                                      





                <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('sms_title', 'SMS Title', array('class' => 'control-label mb-1')) }}
                                      
            {{ Form::text('sms_title',null,['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'sms_title'] )  }}
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('offer_name', 'Offer Name', array('class' => 'control-label mb-1')) }}
                                      
            {{ Form::text('offer_name',null,['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'offer_name'] )  }}
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('sms_content', 'SMS Content', array('class' => 'control-label mb-1')) }}
                                      
            {{ Form::textarea('sms_content',null,['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'sms_content'] )  }}
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('languages', 'Languages', array('class' => 'control-label mb-1')) }}
                                      
            {{ Form::text('languages',null,['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'languages'] )  }}
                                </div>



                                
 
                <div>
                    <button id="payment-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block">
                        <i class="fas fa-sync-alt fa-spin fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;
                        <span id="payment-button-amount">Update</span>
                        <span id="payment-button-sending" style="display:none;">Sending…</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                                  {{ Form::close() }}
                              </div>
                          </div>
```

Comment: try after `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 0):

Change your route to this

```
Route::put('/compose/update/{id}', ['uses'=>'Admin\ComposeController@update','as'=>'compose-update', 'middleware'=> 'permission:All'] );
```

```
{{ Form::model($compose,['url' => ['/compose/update/'.$compose->id],'method'=>'put']) }}
```

Check the routes if you have routes with same name or url. Also run these commands

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: Yeah it is for update but I used post for update also, I just want to see if it works. I have heard HTML form not accept put as method

Comment: when i submit the URL will be http://127.0.0.1:8000/back/compose/update/1

Comment: in another part of my project i have used {{ Form::model($subcategory,['route' => ['update-subcategory',$subcategory->id],'method'=>'put']) }} and it works fine

Comment: try with the url of the route

Comment: what should i do please

Comment: it is working with post method but how can it be it's not normal we use put for the update and post for store

Comment: ```'url' => ['/compose/update/'.$compose->id]```

Comment: 404
Not Found http://127.0.0.1:8000/compose/update/1